# react-native mount component without enzyme

Tags: react-native, enzyme

My test app is built with the latest version of React-Native and React [using the expo app after following guidlines from facebook].

```
  "dependencies": {
     "expo": "18.0.3",
     "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
     "react-native": "0.45.1",
     "react-navigation": "1.0.0-beta.11"
   }
```

Now I'm stuck while writing tests as I cant use enzyme with the latest version of react-native.

Check below thread
https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/928

And now I want to test the componentDidMount, as it fetches data and updates the state of my component for it to re-render.

Now how do I test this without using enzyme. Enzyme had Mount function which made this possible and now I dont have anything but shallow render which comes as part of 'react-test-renderer'

my devdependencies are as follows:

```
  "devDependencies": {
     "jest-expo": "~18.0.0",
     "jsdom": "^11.1.0",
     "react-native-scripts": "0.0.40",
     "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
   },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
      "start": "react-native-scripts start",
      "android": "react-native-scripts android",
      "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --env=jsdom"
   },
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: There is no fix untill React releases a v16 or Enzyme starts supporting alpha releases.